# Need to pass data from one activity to another referencing database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-activity, android-intent

In my application I want to save some string data into an array.

This data should then be fetched by the another activity in a `ListView`.

I am using a database to store the data. But every time I'm storing data in different tables. Now as per my knowledge it is not possible to fetch all the available tables from a defined database.

So what I'm trying to do is, store the table name into the `Array` while it is created. And displaying it in the `ListView`.

Now when I press on the perticular `ListIndex`, it will fetch the data of that table.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just me, but i read this 3 times and still have no clue what you want to do, yet alone what you are asking. Can you rephrase that and maybe add a few code bits to illustrate? Also please use a descriptive title and appropriate tags.

Comment: Ok Sure. I m going to store some data in to the activity and for that table is created while starting of previous activity. I want to store the table name in one array. And in in another activity, i want to show that array of table name. Based on the selection of that perticular table name, i want to fetch the data of that table. hope you got my point of view. So please let me help in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Map of Table Name against Array of Data

```
    // Store
    Map<String, String[]> storage = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    String[] items = {"one","two","three"}; // Your Data
    storage.put("tableName", items);        // Your table name

    // Retrieve a specific table
    String[] tableItems = storage.get("tableName");
    for(String s : tableItems){
        Log.i("TAG", "item name: "+s); // Will loop and print one , two then three
    }

    // Retrive all
    Set<String> allTables = storage.keySet();
    for (String table : allTables) {
        for(String s : storage.get(table)){
            Log.i("TAG", "table name: " + table + "item name: "+s);  // Will loop through each table, (we only have one) and print one , two then three
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

For your comment about sending table names:

```
    String[] items = {"tableOne","tableTwo","tableThree"}; // Your Data
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("sendIntentTableName", items);
    startActivity(intent);

    ... onCreate(){
        String[] tableNames = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("sendIntentTableName");
    }
```

Comment: Ok. Its nice. But instead of that if i want to store only the table name in to the array and then fetch that array from another activity. is it possible ? And if it is then let me know how ??